# How can I use ES6 in vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

```
import routes from "./src/router/routes";

module.exports = {
 // routes
}
```

can not use es6 module here, it gives an error:

```
import routes from "./src/router/routes";
       ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

also require does not work, as routes are ES6 modules (have import statements)

```
const routes = require("./src/router/routes");
```

Comment: `require` is supported. How does it not work for you?

Comment: @tony19 as routes file has import statement further that's why require doesn't work

Comment: For those who are wondering why do I need routes in vue.config.file, to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-sitemap

Answer (score 1):

You must enable the ES6 Modules in NodeJs.

Check this links for enable:

- https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html
- https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-js-12-from-experimental-to-release/

ATTENTION: This resource is experimental

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I think the answer is not right to the context. Mahammad is talking about the VueJS (Frontend). The answer you provided is valid if he talked about the Node JS.